# Handling DB Locks When Multiple Application Servers Updates Data Simultaneously

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

I have 4 ejb clients accessing a POJO class in different Application Servers. This POJO class will write some data to the DB. BUt now when the call for an update a data to the DB comes simultaneously from both the Application Servers, there is a DB lock created and all the data cannot be stored successfully.

Constraint : This class cannnot be made EJB and the Application Server default settings cannot be changed (Eg: Transaction Timeout).

How can solve this issue?

Comment: What is the error?  How long does the first session keep the transaction open?  What is the transaction timeout for the second session?  Why do you have two sessions running on two different application servers updating the same row in the same table?  That's generally not the way you'd want to design a system.

Comment: Error is :  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock . The transaction timeout are default settings of the Application Server.

Comment: What is the transaction timeout on your application server?  Why is there a distributed transaction?  How long do you expect the first transaction to be open while holding the lock?

Answer (score 0):

Your Situation Seems similar to the Concept of Semaphore in Operating System. Why don't you try the same thing by using delay or sleep for some fractions.